# Changing icon every 200 milliseconds

Tags: java, timer

I´m trying to change the icon on a JLabel every 200 milliseconds to simulate rolling a dice and I´ve been searching online and I can´t figure out how to set a Timer so I can run the method.
This is the method

```
public void dice(){
    int whichOne=(int)(Math.random()*6+1);
    if(whichOne==1){jLabel12.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/spanish/dice1.png")));}
    else if(whichOne==2){jLabel12.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/spanish/dice2.png")));}
    else if(whichOne==3){jLabel12.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/spanish/dice3.png")));}
    else if(whichOne==4){jLabel12.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/spanish/dice4.png")));}
    else if(whichOne==5){jLabel12.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/spanish/dice5.png")));}
    else if(whichOne==6){jLabel12.setIcon(new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/spanish/dice6.png")));}
}
```

And this is how I´m currently calling the method

```
for(int i=0;i<9;i++){
    dice();
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html

Comment: Calling this method every 30 ms isn't a good idea for simulating rolling a die, though. This method is unnecessarily heavy on performance and you can get the same number twice in a row, which isn't really what you want. You're probably better off having a second method for the graphical part.

Comment: I agree that 30 milliseconds isn't probably needed, and is going to have performances issues with Swing.  Swing isn't OpenGL it doesn't do fast real time animation.  Look at getting your code working with 100 or 200 milliseconds, then see if it needs improvement.

Comment: Constantly reloading each `ImageIcon` is going to destroy your performance. Store those first.

Comment: Did your searching online happen to include a search for “java timer”?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one solution on how to call `dice` using [`Timer`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html) and [`TimerTask`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html):

```
import java.util.*;

...

private void dieCaller() {
    TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
        int numRolls = 0;

        @Override
        public void run() {
            if (numRolls < 9) {
                dice();
                numRolls++;
            }
            else {
                cancel();
            }
        }
    };

    Timer timer = new Timer("Die Roller");
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(task, 0, 200);
}

...
```

One other problem I have: don't load those `ImageIcon`s everytime. Load them once and save like an array or something to refer to them later.